# How to Make ComboBox must be selected in VB6

Tags: combobox, vb6

How to Make ComboBox must be selected in vb6
and if ComboBox is not selected then showing message "you have not selected a menu"

Answer (score 1):

Mark your ComboBox, let's name it `combo1`, in Property set `CausesValidation` to `true`.

Go to code (F7) and add a subroutine for the validation:

```
Private Sub combo1_Validate(Cancel As Boolean)
  If combo1.ListIndex < 0 Then
    ' Mark somewhere that nothing is selected, like setting a boolean
  End If
End Sub
```

In your OK Button simply check if your mark has been set. Ofc you can just check for listindex in your OK button but this looks cleaner;) `MsgBox` is for Messageboxes;)

Comment: With the exception that the Combobox items are 0 based and -1 indicates no selection, your answer works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
If Combo1.Text = "" Then
MsgBox "You have not selected a menu!"
End If
```

It also depends on what type of combo box, if it's a simple combo box then the code would be instead of

```
If Combo1.Text = "" Then
```

it would be what ever you filled out for the text field to be
[image]

So in the picture I uploaded the text is Combo1 so I would use the code

```
If Combo1.Text = "Combo1" Then
```

Since if it's the same text it had when you loaded the form it will say "Combo1", you would have to modify it to whatever the text is in your case.